# Neo4j Group result based on property

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

I have some data looks like this:

```
{Name: Peter
Gender: Male
Like: movie, game}
{Name:Ame
Gender: Female
Like:dog, movie, hiking}
{Name: Greg
Gender: Male
Like: hiking}
```

I want to group them by what they like and generate a table like:

```
Like: movie //Peter, Ame
count: 2

like: game //Peter
count: 1

like: dog //Ame
count: 1

like: hiking //Ame, Greg
count: 2
```

How can I query to get this result? Or should I redo the schema?
Something like

```
MATCH (person:Person) RETURN DISTINCT person.like AS Like, count(person.like) AS Count
```

This gives me

```
Like: movie, game
Count: 1

Like: dog, movie, hiking
Count: 1

Like: hiking
Count: 1
```

Thank you for helping.

Answer (score 1):

A more graph-oriented data model would be more suitable.

For example, you can have `Person` and `Interest` nodes connected by `LIKES` relationships:

```
MERGE (peter:Person {name: 'Peter', gender: 'M'})
MERGE (ame:Person {name: 'Ame', gender: 'F'})
MERGE (greg:Person {name: 'Greg', gender: 'M'})

MERGE (movies:Interest {name: 'Movies'})
MERGE (games:Interest {name: 'Games'})
MERGE (hiking:Interest {name: 'Hiking'})
MERGE (dogs:Interest {name: 'Dogs'})

MERGE (peter)-[:LIKES]->(movies)
MERGE (peter)-[:LIKES]->(games)
MERGE (ame)-[:LIKES]->(dogs)
MERGE (ame)-[:LIKES]->(movies)
MERGE (ame)-[:LIKES]->(hiking)
MERGE (greg)-[:LIKES]->(hiking);
```

With the above data, you can easily group people by their interests. A couple of examples:

```
MATCH (interest:Interest)
RETURN interest, [(p)-[:LIKES]->(interest) | p] AS people;
```

or

```
MATCH (interest:Interest)<-[:LIKES]-(p)
RETURN interest, COLLECT(p) AS people;
```

The result would be:

```
╒═════════════════╤═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╕
│"interest"       │"people"                                                   │
╞═════════════════╪═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╡
│{"name":"Movies"}│[{"gender":"M","name":"Peter"},{"gender":"F","name":"Ame"}]│
├─────────────────┼───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│{"name":"Games"} │[{"gender":"M","name":"Peter"}]                            │
├─────────────────┼───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│{"name":"Hiking"}│[{"gender":"F","name":"Ame"},{"gender":"M","name":"Greg"}] │
├─────────────────┼───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│{"name":"Dogs"}  │[{"gender":"F","name":"Ame"}]                              │
└─────────────────┴───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `Like` property is an array you could do the following

```
MATCH(person:Person)
UNWIND person.like as like
RETURN like, count(*)
```